# Low speed on converting float stream with pipe, scanf, write

Tags: c, stream, binary

I'm trying to save a continuing data stream (very large) to a binary file.
The data stream is generate with

```
find . -name "(pattern)" | xargs -L1 awk '{(smth)}' | ./translater
```

The "translator" is a **C** code to revive the data flow from the second pipe.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    float buffer;
    FILE *stream;

    stream = fopen("output.bin", "wb");
    while (scanf("%f", &buffer)==1) {
        fwrite(&buffer, 1, sizeof(float), stream);
    }
    fclose(stream);
    return (0);
}
```

These combination works well, but takes too long (>3hr) to generate a 2GB binary file. Is there anything that I can improve in order to turbo it?

Comment: Try reading and writing in larger chunks.

Comment: Are you sure it’s the C program that’s the slow part? You’re re-executing `awk` for every input file. How many input files are there? If you give an example of what `pattern` and `{(smth)}` are, then it will be easier for people to help you answer your question.

Comment: Pipe kernel buffer is rather small. It is likely that most of the time is spent context switching. You may like to profile it. An easy test would be to save outputs into files and then feed the file to the next stage instead of using shell pipes.

Comment: @AndrewNeitsch There are 16200*79*3 input files for total. awk here is just print out the 2nd column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are executing `awk` nearly 4,000,000 times. On my machine it takes about 5 seconds to execute `awk` 1000 times, even though `awk` does nothing. You can time it like this in the shell:

```
time for ((i = 0; i < 1000; i++)); do gawk 1 < /dev/null; done
```

This means that `awk` initialization time alone for your problem would take around `4000 * 5 / 60 / 60 = 5.5` hours, not even doing any work.

Try

```
find . -name "(pattern)" | xargs cat | awk '{print $2}' | ./translater
```

to execute only one `awk` process.

If that is still slow, try timing each part of the timeline by itself—how long does it take `find` to run? How long to `cat` to `/dev/null`? How long to run `awk`?

`fwrite` is usually buffered so that, and your translator program, should not be the problem.

Comment: Thanks Andrew. I have a `if(NR<=141)` (600 lines for each file) in the awk sentence. I tried remove the `if()` inside awk, the program works very fast. Now, I think it was `if` slowed down the routine.

Comment: I updated it with: `find . -name "(pattern)" | xargs see -n '1,141p' | awk '{print $2}' | ./translater` works much better.